# Prove that the rings $K[[x]]/(x^n)$ are artinian for every $n\geq 1$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $K[[x]]$ be the ring of formal power series over a field $K$, and $K[[x]] \supset (x) \supset (x^2) \supset (x^3 )\supset\ldots\supset(x^n )\supset\ldots$ be   uniserial ring (that is, all its ideals are linearly ordered
with respect to inclusion).

Prove that the rings $K[[x]]/(x^n)$ are artinian for every $n\geq 1$.

My reasoning is that $K[[x]]/(x^n)$ is of finite dimension.  (That is, it has a finite basis).  Secondly, the ideals will terminate eventually.  That means it is artinian.  However, I have failed to construct the proof in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have written **the ring has finitely many ideals**. It has $n+1$ to be exact.

From there it is a no-brainer that all chains are eventually constant.